# How to use Java Swing graphics with MPJ MPI Implementation?

Tags: cluster-computing, mpi, hpc

I am learning MPI under Java, and till now I can perfectly write console application in MPJ. But, now I want to mix Java Swing library with MPI. Is it possible? I like to create something like, a small window, with a button a textbox. In textbox you a put a value, and when you click on the jbutton, certain number of MPI processes are started according to the value in the textbox. Is it possible to write such an application, please give me some idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know precisely how you start your MPJ programs, but there are 2 aspects of the usual mode of operation for MPI programs you need to think about.

1. MPI programs are generally started under the control of some initialisation process (such as `mpiexec`) which starts up a number of processes for execution.  This means that an executing MPI program may be (usually is) in an environment where the number of processes is fixed for the duration of execution.  An MPI program is given a number of processes, it does not, during initialisation or execution, acquire them.
2. MPI processes often (usually) execute without a connection to a console so there is no interactive environment to hook together a process and a UI.

So it is a moot point whether writing a SWING-based GUI for an MPJ program is either feasible or useful.  Nor is it clear that that is exactly what you want.  It should be relatively easy for you to write a Java program, with a SWING GUI if you so desire, which interacts not with an executing MPJ program but with the job management system on your parallel computer to initiate the parallel execution of an MPJ program.  The details of writing such a program depend, entirely, on the configuration and capabilities of your platform.